# How to clean up a timer gracefully?

Tags: c#

I have a class that installs a timer through a constructor.

```
public class ScanInput
{
   private Timer m_Timer;
   :
   public ScanInput(bool bAuto)
   {
      Auto = bAuto;

      if (bAuto)
      {
         m_Timer = new Timer();

         m_Timer.Interval = 1000 * DEFAULTTIMERSECONDS;
         m_Timer.Enabled = true;
         m_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimerTick);
      }
      else
         m_Timer = null;
   }
   :
   protected void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       :
   }
}
```

What happens to this object when it goes out of scope on a running timer ? Do I have to implement an IDisposable interface to gracefull stop the timer first and clean it up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class has `IDisposable` fields then it should itself implement `IDisposable` to allow the users of your class to release the unmanaged resources (in your case the underlying OS timer resource).

Microsoft explains the [Dispose Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern):

> **DO** implement the Basic Dispose Pattern on types containing instances of disposable types. See the Basic Dispose Pattern section for details on the basic pattern.

If you don't implement `IDisposable` on your class two things happen:

1. The unmanaged resources used by the timer are not cleaned up when they are no longer used. Instead this happens later when the timer instance is being garbage collected as a result of the timer having a finalizer.
2. The timer unmanaged resources are cleaned up by finalization requiring extra work by the finalizer thread which is best avoided.

While you should certainly try to write optimal code none of these points may make much of a difference in a small application.

In your case implementing `IDisposable` is quite simple:

```
sealed class ScanInput : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        m_Timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It is OK to dispose an already disposed object so you don't have guard the call to `m_Timer.Dispose()`. However, you may want to throw `ObjectDisposedException` in some of your other methods if `ScanInput` has been disposed and the method no longer can perform its work.

The class is sealed to avoid the complexity of both implementing `IDisposable` and allowing derived members to override what gets disposed.

For this to be useful you of course have to dispose the `ScanInput` instance when you are done using it. Otherwise the clean up of the timer unmanaged resource only happens later outside your control.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to implement an IDisposable interface to gracefull stop the
>   timer first and clean it up ?

You should call the `Dispose()` method after you are done using the `Timer` instance. Yes, you can implement `IDisposable` on your class and implement the `Dispose()` method and in your type's dispose implementation you should call the timer dispose